# PHP - How do I reference a class variable (property) of another object which resides inside an object?

Tags: php, variables, object

Maybe the question is a little confusing, lets use an example:

Let's say I have an object (class) of **Team**.

Inside the class I have a class property which is an object (class) of **Player** and I want to access his **jerseyNumber** property, how do I do this?

```
class Team {
    public $player;
}

class Player {
    public $jerseyNumber;
}
```

Bare in mind, I'm new to PHP.

To access a property inside Team, I would just use:

```
$team->player;
```

But it doesn't seem like I can access a property inside player like this (which I'd think would work considering the above):

```
$team->player->jerseyNumber;
```

So how do I access **jerseyNumber**?

Comment: We need more code. `$team->player->jerseyNumber` should work, unless you have some other restrictions.

Comment: I think in order to do that, you need to define `$player` of `Team` as an object of `Player` class:     `public Player $player;`

Comment: I don't think it's even possible to do public Player $player;

Comment: I'm not sure what other code you would need to help you? If that should work, and that's how it's supposed to work, maybe there's something else wrong.

Comment: $player= new Player; created an object, and calling its method, $player->jerseyNumber;

Comment: Sorry, I figured out what was wrong, you're right, $team->player->jerseyNumber would work. Thanks :)

Comment: Here is an example showing how it should work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/uzum5c. As long as you are creating all your instances, what you suggest should work fine. Turning on error reporting should help find whatever issue you are having.

Comment: @Pooya, no. You can only use primitive data types (int, string...etc) when defining a property. http://codepad.viper-7.com/xDjOLO

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to this. I have added a  constructor inside Team. This will help you instantiate the player class inside team class properly as the team class is instantiated. You can then access player properties with team object easily.

*PS Instantiating a class means creating an object of the class.*

You will still need to write code to assign values to $jerseyNumber.

```
class Team {
public $player;



public function  __construct(){
  $this->player = new Player();
    }
}

class Player {
    public $jerseyNumber;
}

$team = new Team;

echo $team->player->jerseyNumber;
```